# Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined in mailgun-js

Tags: javascript, mailgun

I am using mailgun-js to validate emails. I'm implementing the same way as described in the documentation [mailgun-js documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js).
my code :

```
var domain = 'postmaster.xxxx.in';
var api_key = 'pubkey-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({
    apiKey: api_key,
    domain: domain
});


mailgun.validate('test@mail.com', function (err, body) {
    if (body && body.is_valid) {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

But I'm getting error

> Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

I also tried with parse function but it resulting the same with error "Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined"

Comment: Your code is working for me, it goes inside the validate method and prints to console if I write a console.log inside of it.

Comment: @supra28  Can you please share your node.js version,

Comment: Node Version  v8.11.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in mailgun-js version.
I did "npm install mailgun-js" which installed mailgun-js version 0.5

After installing the latest version of mailgun-js through the command

> npm install mailgun-js@latest

the version is now 0.18.0 and things are working perfect.